# how to add value in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to compare a number with a collection of numbers. So for it i want to know how we use use array in javascript and one thing more i want the syntax how to concatenate the values from a collection to this array. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array.push(value); //adding value to the end of the array
var newArray = array.concat(oldArray); //concat array with oldArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this w3schools tutorial, it explains what you asked and more:

[JavaScript Array Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)

Comment: [MDN Array reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is much better